# Multidimensional ArrayListy inizialize

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i have declared this multidimensional ArrayList :

```
public class Rete {

public RequestQueue requestQueue;
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();


public Rete(RequestQueue requestQueue) {
    this.requestQueue = requestQueue;
    result.add(new ArrayList<String>(4));
}
```

}

and i'm traing to add data like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < utenti.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject student = utenti.getJSONObject(i);

                    result.get(i).add(student.getString("nome"));
                    result.get(i).add(student.getString("cognome"));
                    result.get(i).add(student.getString("numero"));
                    result.get(i).add(student.getString("email"));

                }
```

but the app crash... logcat :

```
10-11 20:10:27.048    6429-6429/com.rete.prova.ale.reteale E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rete.prova.ale.reteale, PID: 6429
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.rete.prova.ale.reteale.Rete$4.onResponse(Rete.java:101)
        at com.rete.prova.ale.reteale.Rete$4.onResponse(Rete.java:89)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

the problem is the ArrayList.. how to inizialize them in the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your arraylist

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

and this is where you are going wrong

```
result.get(i).add(student.getString("nome"));
result.get(i).add(student.getString("cognome"));
result.get(i).add(student.getString("numero"));
result.get(i).add(student.getString("email"));
```

you are getting **IndexOutOfBoundsException** because you are trying get object from an empty array.

Try this

```
ArrayList<String> studentdata = new ArrayList<String>();
studentdata.add(student.getString("nome"));
studentdata.add(student.getString("cognome"));
studentdata.add(student.getString("numero"));
studentdata.add(student.getString("email"));

result.add(studentdata);
```

Comment: what is the line where you are getting that error. Have you removed this line from constructor       result.add(new ArrayList<String>(4));

Answer (score 1):

At every iteration of your for loop you need to instantiate a new `ArrayList` and add it to `result`

```
for (int i = 0; i < utenti.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject student = utenti.getJSONObject(i);
        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(4);
        tmp.add(student.getString("nome"));
        tmp.add(student.getString("cognome"));
        tmp.add(student.getString("numero"));
        tmp.add(student.getString("email"));
        result.add(tmp);
}
```

and get rid of

```
result.add(new ArrayList<String>(4));
```

Comment: logcat : prntscr.com/8q8afd